# detect audio feed wmv/wma stream

Tags: vbscript, wmv, wma

I am trying to find an application or code to monitor an audio stream for silence or black video frames and send an email alert when no audio is detected or

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small c# app to do that.

It's a command line app which could be used by a batch script to check if there's some audio playing.

I use it with the following piece of code:

...

```
:getAudioLevels
FOR /F "DELIMS=- TOKENS=1,2 skip=1" %%A IN ('CXVolumeMeter.exe') DO (
    SET left=%%A
    SET right=%%B
)
GOTO:EOF
```

Here a link where you can download it:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1163492/Uploads/CXVolumeMeter.exe

It works only on Windows vista/Seven.

Once you get the values of right and left channels, you can script as you want.

Cheers!

Comment: I think it is better if you include the source to the program, if you don't mind. Just the binary file is quite unassuring, as no one knows what is actually done behind the scene.